# Sum subitems in TListView

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

How we can sum some SubItems in TListView? If you look at picture in below,

[image]

Fist, we fill `Col 1` to `Col 4` for `Group1` and `Group2`. The problem is, how we can sum the SubItems `Col 2` and put the result in `Col 3`. The picture i post at above is clear, but if i want to explain for how to sum, Its kinda you sum current SubItem of ListView with above SubItem. And, for first SubItem in each group we put same number like `Col 2`.

Comment: You can just add the numbers together using the `+` operator. If you can populate the tree view, then surely you can add the numbers as you are going along.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this might do what you want:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  Value: Integer;
  GroupID: Integer;
  GroupSum: Integer;
begin
  GroupID := 0;
  GroupSum := 0;
  for I := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if Assigned(ListView1.Items[I].SubItems) and
      (ListView1.Items[I].SubItems.Count > 0) and
      TryStrToInt(ListView1.Items[I].SubItems[0], Value) then
    begin
      if GroupID <> ListView1.Items[I].GroupID then
      begin
        GroupSum := 0;
        GroupID := ListView1.Items[I].GroupID;
      end;
      GroupSum := GroupSum + Value;
      if ListView1.Items[I].SubItems.Count < 2 then
        ListView1.Items[I].SubItems.Add(IntToStr(GroupSum))
      else
        ListView1.Items[I].SubItems[1] := IntToStr(GroupSum);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Well, for those who want to simulate OP's situation, here's a code (just place a list view component on a form and write the event handler):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ListItem: TListItem;
  ListGroup: TListGroup;
  ListColumn: TListColumn;
begin
  ListView1.Clear;
  ListView1.GroupView := True;
  ListView1.ViewStyle := vsReport;

  ListColumn := ListView1.Columns.Add;
  ListColumn.Caption := 'Column 1';
  ListColumn.Width := 90;
  ListColumn := ListView1.Columns.Add;
  ListColumn.Caption := 'Column 2';
  ListColumn.Width := 90;
  ListColumn := ListView1.Columns.Add;
  ListColumn.Caption := 'Column 3';
  ListColumn.Width := 90;

  ListGroup := ListView1.Groups.Add;
  ListGroup.GroupID := 0;
  ListGroup.Header := 'Group 1';
  ListGroup := ListView1.Groups.Add;
  ListGroup.GroupID := 1;
  ListGroup.Header := 'Group 2';

  ListItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
  ListItem.GroupID := 0;
  ListItem.Caption := 'Item 1';
  ListItem.SubItems.Add('22');
  ListItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
  ListItem.GroupID := 0;
  ListItem.Caption := 'Item 2';
  ListItem.SubItems.Add('11');
  ListItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
  ListItem.GroupID := 1;
  ListItem.Caption := 'Item 3';
  ListItem.SubItems.Add('94');
  ListItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
  ListItem.GroupID := 1;
  ListItem.Caption := 'Item 4';
  ListItem.SubItems.Add('42');
  ListItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
  ListItem.GroupID := 1;
  ListItem.Caption := 'Item 5';
  ListItem.SubItems.Add('21');
end;
```

Comment: This misses the fact that most likely the raw data is in a data structure with integer values. In which case there's no cause for StrToInt. It would be foolish to populate the list view with strings, forget about the underlying data and then try to sum it up.

Comment: @David, since the question is missing the information if OP uses list view in virtual mode or not, I've used this way. If it's foolish or not I don't care, the important part is storing the group sum in this case, which is not mentioned in your favorite comment.

Comment: Well, that's implicit in that comment. But even assuming non-virtual list, there must be some data structure behind this. And there must be some code to populate list based on the content of that data structure. And it's at the point at which the list view is populated that the summing should be done. And that's how you can make sure you only ever use `IntToStr` and never have to use `StrToInt`. You see what I mean?

Comment: @David, now I see what you mean. Yeah, that's right. Just to add, when there would be a way to modify those values, you would have to recalculate sums in the group to which the *edited* subitem belongs for the items starting from the *edited* one to the last item of that group.

Comment: Sure, if you start editing this data then it gets more tricky. But at that point surely you'd reflect the edits back to the underlying data, and then my point of view is still valid. Or you do the whole thing virtual, and the same arguments apply. Anyway, you've made a good job of the question that was in front of you which is why I upvoted.